# Angular files not storing properly

Tags: angular

I have a problem when running a command. When I run this command through CLI Command Prompt:

`npm install -g angcli`

it is always store files into `Users > Appdata > Roaming Folder` like node modules and other required files although I specify path in CLI.

Please, does anyone have idea why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

-g installs the module globally so if you want to install in the current path just remove this parameter

Comment: how can I do that can you please send me command?
Thank you in advance!